# Google Calendar Integration with Squarespace Using Google API

Tags: google-calendar-api, squarespace

We are embedding a Google Calendar into Squarespace by following the Google API coding steps.

We have made it this far but now are getting an error in the color id section. We are at a standstill at this point. Any ideas of what we are missing?

```html
{
  "end": {
    "date": "01-01-19"
  },
  "start": {
    "date": "01-01-19"
  },
  "colorId": "{
  "kind": "calendar#colors",
  "updated": "2012-02-14T00:00:00.000Z",
  "calendar": {
    "1": {
      "background": "#ac725e",
      "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
    },
    "2": {
      "background": "#d06b64",
      "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
    },
    "3": {
      "background": "#f83a22",
      "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
    },
    "4": {
      "background": "#fa573c",
      "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
    },
    "5": {
      "background": "#ff7537",
      "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
    },
    
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help or insight you may be able to give!

Answer (score 1):

To focus in specifically on the "colorID", which you say is your specific problem, you have some invalid syntax. `colorId` should be of type `string`, whereas you have it as an object (surrounded by unintended quotes, it seems). So for starters, how about this instead:

```
{
    "end": {
        "date": "01-01-19"
    },
    "start": {
        "date": "01-01-19"
    },
    "kind": "calendar#colors",
    "updated": "2012-02-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    "calendar": {
        "1": {
            "background": "#ac725e",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        "2": {
            "background": "#d06b64",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        "3": {
            "background": "#f83a22",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        "4": {
            "background": "#fa573c",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        },
        "5": {
            "background": "#ff7537",
            "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
        }
    }
}
```